# How to share ansible variables between loop tasks

Tags: ansible, fortinet

I'm trying to create a Fortinet FortiManager automation with their Ansible [collection](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/fortinet/fortimanager/index.html).

I've created a dynamic ADOM creation task which runs in a loop and now I'm trying to run another dynamic tasks that creates CLI templates inside all of the created ADOM's. The problem I'm facing is that I have to defined ADOM name multiple times in different tasks that run in a loop, but what I would like to do is inherit/share the ADOM name between loop tasks so I do not have to repeatedly define it for each loop task with another variable name.

This is the code I have with descriptions:

1. I've created a task that includes ADOM creation tasks and runs it in
   a loop for each ADOM I need to create. I need to do this due to the
   fact that FortiManager ADOM creation task state result does not give *"OK"* if the ADOM is already created, but it fails. So I had
   to build it like this.

```
---
  name: 'Setup ADOMS'
  loop: '{{ fmg_adom_list }}'
  loop_control:
    loop_var: '__adom'
    label: '{{ __adom.fmg_adom_name }}'
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks: 'fmg_setup_adom.yml'
```

2. This is the ADOM creation task and check if ADOM exists to skip the
   creation

```
 - name: Check if ADOM exists
  fortinet.fortimanager.fmgr_fact:
    facts:
      selector: "dvmdb_adom"
      params:
        adom: "{{ __adom.fmg_adom_name }}"
  register: fmg_adom_check
  no_log: false
  ignore_errors: true
  changed_when: "fmg_adom_check.rc != 0"
  failed_when: "fmg_adom_check.rc == -3"

 - name: "Create ADOM {{ __adom.fmg_adom_name }}"
  fortinet.fortimanager.fmgr_dvmdb_adom:
    bypass_validation: "{{ fmg_bypass_validation }}"
    state: "{{ __adom.fmg_adom_state | default('present') }}"
    dvmdb_adom:
      name: "{{ __adom.fmg_adom_name | replace(' ', '_') }}"
      desc: "{{ __adom.fmg_adom_desc }}"
      os_ver: "{{ __adom.fmg_adom_os_ver | default(7.0) | float }}"
      mode: "{{ __adom.fmg_adom_mode | default('gms') }}"
      restricted_prds: "{{ __adom.fmg_adom_restricted_prds | default('fos') }}"
      state: " {{ __adom.fmg_dvmdb_adom_state | default(1) | int }}"
      flags: "{{ __adom.fmg_adom_flags }}"
  register: fmg_adom_create
  when: fmg_adom_check.meta.response_message == "Object does not exist"

 - name: Print ADOM creation error message
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "Failed to create ADOM: {{ fmg_adom_check.meta.response_message }}"
  when: fmg_adom_create is failed

 - name: Print ADOM already exists message
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "ADOM {{ __adom.fmg_adom_name }} already exists"
  when: fmg_adom_create is skipped

 - name: Print ADOM created successfully message
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "ADOM {{ __adom.fmg_adom_name }} created successfully"
  when: fmg_adom_create is succeeded and fmg_adom_create is not skipped
```

3. This is the CLI template task that gives me a error: `The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'fmg_adom_name'`. I'm stuck on understanding how can I make the task use `fmg_adom_name` from ADOM creation variable list, instead of needed to repeat the variable with a new name like `fmg_tmpl_grp_adom` as the ADOM is a mandatory variable.

```
---
- name: Create CLI template group {{ item.fmg_tmpl_grp_name }} to ADOM {{ item.fmg_adom_name }}
  fortinet.fortimanager.fmgr_templategroup:
    workspace_locking_adom: "{{ item.fmg_adom_name }}"
    adom: "{{ item.fmg_adom_name }}"
    state: "{{ item.fmg_tmpl_grp_state }}"
    templategroup:
      name: "{{ item.fmg_tmpl_grp_name }}"
      description: "{{ item.fmg_tmpl_grp_desc }}"
      member: "{{ item.fmg_tmpl_grp_mbr | list }}"
  loop: "{{ fmg_tmpl_grp_list | zip(fmg_adom_list) | list }}"
```

4. These are the variables that I define in the playbook

```
# ADOM Creation variables
    fmg_adom_list: 
      - fmg_adom_name: "ADOM_One"
        fmg_adom_desc: "ADOM One"
        fmg_adom_flags:
          - no_vpn_console
          - per_device_wtp
          - per_device_fsw
# ADOM CLI Template group creation varibles
    fmg_tmpl_grp_list:
      - fmg_tmpl_grp_state: present
        fmg_tmpl_grp_name: "Test"
        fmg_tmpl_grp_desc: "Test group"
        fmg_tmpl_grp_mbr: 
          - "test_cli_template"
```

I hope I explained myself as clearly and understandably as possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're zipping two lists together which means you end up with a list of two-tuples, ie. each element of the list is itself a list. Hence accessing the `fmg_adom_name` attribute of a list item (instead of the expected dictionary) results in the observed error.

You need to access `[0]` for the adom information and `[1]` for the template information.

```yaml
- name: Create CLI template group {{ item[1].fmg_tmpl_grp_name }} to ADOM {{ item[0].fmg_adom_name }}
  fortinet.fortimanager.fmgr_templategroup:
    workspace_locking_adom: "{{ item[0].fmg_adom_name }}"
    adom: "{{ item[0].fmg_adom_name }}"
    state: "{{ item[1].fmg_tmpl_grp_state }}"
    templategroup:
      name: "{{ item[1].fmg_tmpl_grp_name }}"
      description: "{{ item[1].fmg_tmpl_grp_desc }}"
      member: "{{ item[1].fmg_tmpl_grp_mbr }}"
  loop: "{{ fmg_tmpl_grp_list | zip(fmg_adom_list) }}"
```

Side note, this will map the first adom to the first template, the second adom to the second template, etc. If that's not what you want `zip` isn't the right filter.

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer. As I understand if I want to loop through all the templates on all of the ADOM's I shouldn't use `zip` as the filter. My question would be if I want all of the templates on all ADOM's then which filter should I be using for the loop to get ADOM names and loop over them.

Comment: If you need a Cartesian product, `ansible.builtin.product` (which maps to Pythons `itertools.product`). The resulting elements will have the same format so you only have to change the filter.